# NetSuite workflow to update a record of different type

Tags: workflow, netsuite

I have two NetSuite records that have a parent-child relationship. Let's call them P and C

The Child records (e.g. C123,124, etc) are listed on the Parent (P987) in a sublist.

I have a need to display the most recently updated child record (e.g. C124) in the main area of the related Parent record. I need to display 3 fields from that child record:

- name
- field1
- field2

Second question: I might need to make one or more of fields displayed above (e.g. field1) editable. If so, would I have to store that as fields on the parent also?  And then how would I keep this "copy" updated in sync with that specific Child record?

It doesn't have to be a workflow but I prefer to use "supported" features (such out of the box workflow actions) as much as possible and avoid customization by scripting.  If you don't think it can be done without a script then please be clear.

P.S. Fairly new to NetSuite but not the concepts.

P.P.S. no I am not happy about the problem above and wish I could prevent all silly requests. lol

Answer (score 0):

First one you can achieve with a Workflow action script.

Second question, if those are custom fields, you'd have to make them populate the info on the child record, this can be done from the same WFA script.

Comment: That's cheating.  With a script you can do a lot of things that a workflow cannot do.  A workflow script is still a script.  For purposes of maintaining this solution (and delegating that maintenance to a lower expertise) I would like to know if this is possible within a pure workflow that one can build in the UI.

Comment: Workflows won't allow interactions to child items, I believe until the next release or 2018.